# Activate gps prompt phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I searched and found that programming on android is possible to make a prompt to appear for turn gps on in an app. Using this:
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS

I want to do the same for a phonegap application but I haven't found anything yet. Just how to make a notification window but not the gps prompt.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: check http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html documentation for Geo Location by phoneagp... Best of luck

Comment: Thanks. I already read it but there is nothing about switch turn gps on inside app. Just about its use...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a plugin that calls native Java code you want to execute. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365052/call-android-service-from-html5-button-phonegap) on how to do that and the relevant phonegap documentation [here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

Hope it helps!