# Call Android Service from HTML5 Button (phonegap)

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-service

I have written an android application using jquerymobile, phonegap and html5 that calls a webservice to get any updates. Lets call that function "Sync". I have also scheduled "Sync" to run every 15 minutes by using *setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);*. The issue I was facing was that since this an HTML5 application, "Sync" would only run if the application was in the foreground. So I developed an android service and moved the "Sync" logic to the java service layer.

Now, my issue is that, users have a button that manually calls the "Sync" function.

My question to you is: **"Can I bind my HTML button to trigger or restart my Android Service"?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by creating a custom phonegap plugin so that I could bind the html button to start my service.

```
   public class MyJSInterface extends CordovaPlugin {

        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if (action.equals("startSync")) {
                this.startSync(args.getString(0), args.getString(1));
                callbackContext.success();
                return true;
            }
         }}
```

And then the js code

```
window.MyJSInterface = {
startAutoSync: function(username, password, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
            console.log('Failed to execute startSync native code');
        }, 
        "MyJSInterface", 
        "startSync", 
        [username, password]
    );
}}
```